# iPad Application Deployment Options for End-Users for Multiple Clients with separate DB and Servers

Tags: ios, ipad

We have multiple clients with their separate databases and servers. We recently built an iPad mobile application and have currently hard coded the URLs of the different servers of our clients and therefore have different instances of the same app.

Given this situation, how can we make the app available to the end users? The app store won't work cause of the situation above and the iOS enterprise version can only be used for in house distribution.

Comment: With only two ways to distribute native ios app for non-jailbroken devices a)App Store b)In-House distribution. I don't think there is another distribution mechanism or channel.

Comment: Can our clients register for the enterprise version and then we as vendors provide them our app?

Comment: Yes, sending ipa to clients should be fine. Once they have enterprise account set up with Apple, clients can codesign your app with their certificate and use it for in house distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way of deploying Apps to devices without the App store or In-House Distribution. You can provision the device using development and distribution provisioning profiles, but they will expire and have to be rebuilt and re provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

Check out an MDM provider like AirWatch or Zenprise.  It might be able to help with the distribution of apps and manage the process.